# How to properly translate R code using list2env and apply into a function

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

I'm a new user here, I hope my question will be clear.

I've written a piece of code that is already working, but i'd like to make a function out of it for more general use. However, I'm experiencing the error: `error in match.fun(FUN)`.
It seems to me that a lot of mistakes can make this error happen, therefore I haven't found an answer that helps me yet.

I do think it has something to do with an apply that I use in my code, as I encountered some other posts that experienced problems when using apply inside a function I think.

I've found the list2env function already somewhere on this site, which is a pretty neat way to read all files in my folders at once (If someone knows a more conventional way, please tell me).

```
setwd("myfolder")
Nsets = list.files(pattern="[[:digit:]]*_")
list2env(
  lapply(setNames(Nsets, 
                  make.names(gsub("[[:digit:]]*_([[:upper:]]*)_[[:lower:]]*",
                                  "\\1n", Nsets))),
         read.table, nrows = 1, header = T, sep = "\t"), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

So the function I'm trying to make of it looks like this:

```
read.from.folder <- function(wd, mypattern, from, to, myrows){
   setwd(wd)
   files <- list.files(pattern=mypattern)
   list2env(
    lapply(setNames(files, make.names(gsub(from, to, files)),
                    read.table, header = T, sep = "\t", 
                    na.strings = c("", " ", NA, "[Not Available]", 
                                   "[Not   Evaluated]", "[Unknown]"),
                    nrows = myrows)),
    envir = .GlobalEnv))
}
```

When using the arguments from the first piece of code, it returns the error in match.fun(FUN).

```
 read.from.folder(wd = "myfolder",
                  mypattern = "[[:digit:]]*_",
                  from = "[[:digit:]]*_([[:upper:]]*)_[[:lower:]]*",
                  to = "\\1n",
                  myrows = 1)
```

Can someone see what is happening here, did I forget to add something stupid, or can't I translate my code into this function this easily?

Comment: Do not (mis)use `list2env` here. It was never intended for assigning into the global environment. Best practice is to keep the data.frames together in a list.

Comment: Yeah anytime I see somebody assigning a whole bunch of related objects to the global environment I always wonder what the plan is when they want to do the same thing to every one of the objects.  Keeping them in a list gives a natural way to do that operation and even if you just want to operate on a single one of them it's the difference between its name being `object1` and `object[[1]]` so it's not really that inconvenient.

Comment: @Dason I found the use to read in all the files in my folder in a thread on this website, I tought it was nice. To operate on all dfs afterwards I tought of get(df) for each df in my 'files' of 'Nset' (which was list.files), and then do what I need to do?

If I'd put them in a list, what would be the good practice to do that? can I keep the apply function to read and fix the names of dfs in one step? 
And then instead of using list2env just assign it to a an empty list? Or what keywords should I use to look for a thread that covers this?

Comment: @Dason I just tried replacing the list2env function by assigning the lapply to a value, that works. And making a function out of it works as well. I just did not know what the conventional way of doing this was. Thanks for the info.